# Why if i don't implement serializable i still can serialize an object?

Tags: java, serializable

I read one book where they say if you don't implement Serializable you can't serialize the given object. But i tried it out without implementing it and it works. Here is some code:

```
import java.io.*;

class SerializerTest {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    public SerializerTest(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SerializerTest st = new SerializerTest(10, 20);
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("st.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
            os.writeObject(st);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

But i noticed that if you implement Serializable the `st.ser` file becomes like 10 times smaller. So why i can serialize something which does not implements Serializable and why the file becomes shorter if i implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject` accepts a parameter of the type `Object`, not `Serializable`. That is why the compiler does not complain and it compiles the program.

However during the run time, the method `writeObject` fails and throws an `NotSerializableException`. In your program the exception is caught and ignored. Just try to add to the `catch` block `e.printStackTrace()` to see.

(or event better, do not wrap the code to `try-catch` at all, simply change the method declaration to `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException`.)